# C# Async function exits thread after third use

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await, dispatcher, windows-iot-core-10

I am writing code for an UWP app which runs on a Raspberry Pi and Windows IoT.

I got a physical Button(https://shkspr.mobi/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Push-Button-Pi.jpg) 
and an RFID reader (http://www.baaqii.com/promanage/productimage/Ewhole/A/A901-2.jpg)

Every time I press the button I want the app to show a popup. When I hold an RFID chip to the RFID reader it should show a certain HTML file in its webview.

Everything works fine but it only works 2 times. After the third RFID identification I always get a DebugMessage like this

```
The thread 0xb50 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xbd4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x488 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x94c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x22c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x720 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

And the button and RFID reader dont work anymore. I think there's an issue with the Dispatcher.

Here are the four functions:

```
private async void Button_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs e) {
                if (e.Edge == GpioPinEdge.RisingEdge) {
                    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
                        this.myHandler_ButtonPushed.Handle(new EventArgs());
                    });
                }
        }



private async void RFID_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Edge == GpioPinEdge.RisingEdge) {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
                this.myHandler_RfidIdentificated.Handle(new EventArgs());
            });
        }
    }


public void Button_pushed(EventArgs e) {
            popup1.IsOpen = true;
    }


public void Rfid_identificated(EventArgs e) {
     webview1.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(webview1.BuildLocalStreamUri("buttonURL", "/myDownloads/de-DE/47430155.html"), new Classes.StreamUriWinRTResolver());
     popup1.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

Comment: You should not use **async void** because after calling such method there are no information when it ends.

Comment: @Thowk It's OK when it's an event, in fact it's really the _only_ time it's OK.

Comment: Without the RFID part, your code works for me. You can post a code sample here for reproducing your issue.

Comment: The error should be in your button state reader code or in the RFID code. There is nothing wrong with what you've show. You should share your code behind the myHandler_XXXX methods.